# Migrating to Dagger 2.12 and test module overrides

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am migrating from Dagger 2.0.2 to Dagger 2.12 and plan to utilize `dagger.android` API.

My question is about migrating the test code. Currently, I have an `AppModule` and a `TestAppModule` which extends it and overrides some dependencies using `@Override` annotation. Here is an example:

```
@Module
public class TestAppModule extends AppModule {

    @Override
    public UserDao provideUserDao() {
        return mock(UserDao.class);
    }
}
```

Now with Dagger 2.12, if I try overriding a dependency in 
`TestAppModule`, an error is thrown: `error: @Provides methods may not be overridden in modules.`

What is the recommended way of **overriding and mocking some of the dependencies** in a `TestModule` while utilizing the rest of the dependencies defined in `AppModule` as is?

I can post a stripped down version of my Dagger setup if people think it's necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up solving it by simply not annotating the `TestAppModule` with `@Module`. This achieves partial mocking.

```
public class TestAppModule extends AppModule {

    @Override
    public UserDao provideUserDao() {
        return mock(UserDao.class);
    }
}
```